# Determine current DST status when I don't observe DST in my timezone (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, timezone, dst

I'm receiving data feeds from a number of different servers across the country, and the items come in timestamped with GMT. I know the GMT offset for each of the locations for standard time, but I'm not sure which locations support/observe Daylight Time. Normally, I'd just check my local time to see what the offset is and then go from there - I could easily determine if DST is currently observed because of the current offset from GMT) - except that my server sits in Arizona, where DST is not observed. As a result, I'm always GMT-7, regardless of whether DST is currently active.

Is there an easy way to determine if DST is being observed when my local server doesn't change time? I could even write a .NET SQL-CLR component that checks something on the system if I need to, though I'd ideally like to do it directly from T-SQL code if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately SQL Server provides no explicit DST flags or functions.

However, after DST takes effect this year you can compile a new list of offsets for each server, `datediff(hh,getutcdate(),getdate())`, and compare it with your current list of standard time offsets. You can then infer DST observance wherever you see a change.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this, but it's a possibility - I know where each data stream originates, so I can just pick a server in each timezone and keep track of its response to this question, and then adjust the datetime values accordingly. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome. I think you'll need to check all the servers since DST observance can vary within a time zone, e.g. Indianapolis.

Comment: The problem is that the SQL Servers aren't what sending the streams, and I don't have a SQL Server in the same city as every source. It's approximation at best, so I think I'll probably be storing the adjusted time and the assumed offset along with it, so if the offset is incorrect for some reason I can always alter it easily later.